# How to hook into Ember Auth rememberable response

Tags: ember.js

Even though [Ember Auth](http://ember-auth.herokuapp.com/docs) doesn't automatically inject custom objects returned upon Sign In, it allows you to grab them by inspecting the *response* object:

```
actions:
signIn: ->
  @auth.signIn(
    data:
      user:
        email: @get 'email'
        password: @get 'password'
  ).then( (response) ->
    console.log response['user_context']['roles']
  )
```

The Sign In action is triggered by my Log In page's submit button, and, in turn, calls the authentication API service.

However, when *rememberable* is used and the page is refreshed, Ember Auth calls the API service with the *remember token* and retrieves the same response object as the Sign In action.

How can I grab the *response* object in this scenario? I need to be able to have access to objects such as user permissions/roles, so that I can build menu bar items based on them. This is just one example.

UPDATE:

Pretty much right after asking this question I realized EmberAuth wasn't gonna cut it for my needs. So I rolled my own Authentication solution. Wasn't as hard as I thought, and much lighter and easier for me to use/customize than the alternative - [SimpleAuth](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth).